# Why did Harvey Bilchik have to fly into town in the movie UHF?

Tags: plot-explanation, uhf

At the beginning of the film [*UHF* (1989)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098546/) the main character of the film, George Newman, gets hired by his uncle Harvey Bilchik to manage a TV station that he just won in a poker game. The details of the scene seem to establish that Harvey and George live in the same town as the TV station.

- George is at a party at his uncle's home
- George is wearing his uniform from the fast food job he was just fired from that day
- Harvey mentions that the television station is "on the edge of town"
- George doesn't move to another town to become station manager as his best friend and girlfriend are still a part of his life after taking the job

Later in the film, Harvey flies into town to determine whether or not to sell the station to pay his gambling debt back to Big Louie. We know he is flying into town because he is greeted by RJ Fletcher, the rival TV station manager. **But if he lives in the same town as the station as previously established, then why the heck is he flying into town?**

Comment: [Yankovic: "I thought that the story was the weakest part of it—why did we try and make it more conventional?"](https://film.avclub.com/we-got-it-all-on-uhf-an-oral-history-of-weird-al-yan-1798278657) The story is leaning on lots of tropes, in this case the uncle is simply a means for George to get this opportunity; by being his uncle he is close enough for that to happen, yet at the same time there is a distance so George can do whatever he wants unsupervised.

Comment: Does the movie ever establish where uncle Harvey does his gambling?  Possibly flies to Atlantic City or Vegas for at least some of his wagers

Comment: In the opening scenes he is gambling at home since he goes directly from the poker game to the party.